# When does the underlying map of a polynomial induce a permutation on $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, permutations, finite-fields

For example, the underlying function of the polynomial
$$f(x)=4x^2-3x^7$$ induces a permutation on $\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z}$, though I only know the proof by "brutal force" (is there a cleverer proof?).

In general, is there a criterion determining if a polynomial $f(x)$ induces a permutation on $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

**Edit**: I am not even sure if it matters whether $p$ is prime or not but I will tag this question "finite fields" for now. Does it matter?

Answer (score 8):

Such polynomials are called *permutation polynomials*. There is a lot of literature on this, a starting point can be the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_polynomial).

For a finite field $F_q$, one does not have to check all possible values. There is a polynomial-time algorithm known to check whether a given rational function (hence in particular polynomial) induces a permutation, see e.g. [Recognizing permutation functions in polynomial time, Neeraj Kayal](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3d5b/e8a2fffcecbd0fa0b5af34c8c6fd90462789.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! Just curious about one point: Is not checking all possible values at $\mathbb{F}_q$ also a polynomial-time algorithm?

Comment: It looks like the result cited in wikipedia is for rational functions $\frac{g}{h}$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$. If $n=\max\{\deg g, \deg h\}$ then its representation is $O(n \log q)$ bits. So, the algorithm is polynomial in input size.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_polynomial) has the answer:

> Let $\mathbb F_q$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$. Then $f \in \mathbb F_q[x]$ is a permutation polynomial iff $f$ has exactly one root in $\mathbb F_q$ and for each integer $t$ with $1 \le t \le q-2$ and $t\not\equiv 0 \bmod p$, the degree of $f(x)^t \bmod (x^q-x)$ is at most $q-2$.

This is known as Hermite's criterion.

See also these surveys:

- [Permutation polynomials over finite fields — A survey of recent advances](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ffa.2014.10.001) (2015)
- [Permutation polynomials of finite fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6044v1) (2012)